# Change headers and row titles after Kendo UI Grid loads after transposing the columns into rows

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid, transpose

I chose to use following method to transpose columns into rows in Kendo UI grid
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/transposed-grid
But the issue is that I cannot use spaces and special characters like % for row titles. I was able to make it display with headers like FT_2003 and row titles like cost_of_good_sold. I would like to remove the underscores and also add some special characters like % and also make headers start with a number. 2003 instead of FY_2003. Thank you.

```
**desired:**
$'000                   2015    2016    2017    2018
Sales                   300     400     350      500 
Cost of goods sold      175      225     200     300 
Gross margin            125      175     150     200 
Gross margin %          41.7%   43.8%   42.9%   40.0%
            
**actual:**
mesure                 FY_2015  FY_2016 FY_2017 FY_2018
Sales                   300     400     350      500 
Cost_of_goods sold      175      225     200     300 
Gross_margin            125      175     150     200 
Gross_margin_percent   41.7     43.8    42.9    40.0
```

Comment: In the line `data[i]["Property"] = property`, you can set that value to what you want, spaces and everything.

Comment: GaloisGirl, Thank YOU! It works!

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to post a full code sample as a response for people ion the future.

Comment: GaloisGirl, One thing seems to be still not totally fixed though, the header of the columns. The underscore is still present in FY_2015.